# how to fix incorrect color for nodes in networkD3 (sankeyNetwork)?

Tags: r, d3.js, htmlwidgets, networkd3

Hi and thanks for reading me
Im workin with a Sankey plot with the networkD3 package and im trying to customize the colors for each node, but im getting an entire column of "source" with the same color and I want to get diferent colors with an specific palette. Anyone know's how I can fix it? The code im using is the following:

```
library(networkD3)
data_long <-data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  source = c("Objetivo 1",
             "Objetivo 1","Objetivo 2","Objetivo 3",
             "Objetivo 4","Objetivo 1","Objetivo 2",
             "Objetivo 3","Objetivo 4",
             "Objetivo 1","Objetivo 2","Objetivo 3",
             "Objetivo 4","Objetivo 1",
             "Objetivo 2","Objetivo 3","Objetivo 4",
             "Objetivo 1","Objetivo 4",
             "Objetivo 4"),
  target = c("ODS 12: Producción y consumo responsables",
             "ODS 17: Alianzas para lograr los objetivos",
             "ODS 10: Reducción de las desigualdades",
             "ODS 10: Reducción de las desigualdades",
             "ODS 17: Alianzas para lograr los objetivos","ODS 3: Salud y bienestar",
             "ODS 12: Producción y consumo responsables",
             "ODS 12: Producción y consumo responsables",
             "ODS 9: Industria, innovación e infraestructura",
             "ODS 8: Trabajo decente y crecimiento económico",
             "ODS 8: Trabajo decente y crecimiento económico",
             "ODS 8: Trabajo decente y crecimiento económico",
             "ODS 8: Trabajo decente y crecimiento económico",
             "ODS 9: Industria, innovación e infraestructura",
             "ODS 9: Industria, innovación e infraestructura",
             "ODS 9: Industria, innovación e infraestructura",
             "ODS 9: Industria, innovación e infraestructura",
             "ODS 5: Igualdad de género",
             "ODS 10: Reducción de las desigualdades",
             "ODS 12: Producción y consumo responsables"),
  value = c(2L,1L,3L,1L,2L,1L,
            3L,1L,1L,19L,1L,11L,13L,15L,
            8L,4L,4L,1L,1L,1L)
)


my_color <- 'd3.scaleOrdinal() .domain(["Objetivo 1", "Objetivo 2","Objetivo 3", "Objetivo 4","ODS 3: Salud y bienestar", "ODS 5: Igualdad de género", "ODS 9: Industria, innovación e infraestructura", "ODS 10: Reducción de las desigualdades", "ODS 12: Producción y consumo responsables", "ODS 17: Alianzas para lograr los objetivos"]) 
.range(["#12A09A", "#1E5C4F" , "#941B80", "#F19100", "#4C9F38", "#FF3A21", "#FD6925", "#DD1367", "#BF8B2E", "purple", "#001B8C"])'

nodes <- data.frame(name=c(as.character(data_long$source), as.character(data_long$target)) %>% unique())


data_long$IDsource=match(data_long$source, nodes$name)-1 
data_long$IDtarget=match(data_long$target, nodes$name)-1

sankeyNetwork(Links = data_long, Nodes = nodes,
              Source = "IDsource", Target = "IDtarget",
              Value = "value", NodeID = "name", 
              sinksRight=FALSE, colourScale=my_color, 
              nodeWidth=40, fontSize=13, nodePadding=20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node group is inferred by the node name unless explicitly specified, and the node group can not have spaces in the name.

You can add a node group column to your nodes data frame like this

```r
nodes$node_group <- gsub(" ", "_", nodes$name)
```

and then specify that column as the node group with the `sankeyNetwork()` argument `NodeGroup = "node_group"`

all together...

```r
library(networkD3)
library(dplyr)

data_long <-data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  source = c("Objetivo 1",
             "Objetivo 1","Objetivo 2","Objetivo 3",
             "Objetivo 4","Objetivo 1","Objetivo 2",
             "Objetivo 3","Objetivo 4",
             "Objetivo 1","Objetivo 2","Objetivo 3",
             "Objetivo 4","Objetivo 1",
             "Objetivo 2","Objetivo 3","Objetivo 4",
             "Objetivo 1","Objetivo 4",
             "Objetivo 4"),
  target = c("ODS 12: Producción y consumo responsables",
             "ODS 17: Alianzas para lograr los objetivos",
             "ODS 10: Reducción de las desigualdades",
             "ODS 10: Reducción de las desigualdades",
             "ODS 17: Alianzas para lograr los objetivos","ODS 3: Salud y bienestar",
             "ODS 12: Producción y consumo responsables",
             "ODS 12: Producción y consumo responsables",
             "ODS 9: Industria, innovación e infraestructura",
             "ODS 8: Trabajo decente y crecimiento económico",
             "ODS 8: Trabajo decente y crecimiento económico",
             "ODS 8: Trabajo decente y crecimiento económico",
             "ODS 8: Trabajo decente y crecimiento económico",
             "ODS 9: Industria, innovación e infraestructura",
             "ODS 9: Industria, innovación e infraestructura",
             "ODS 9: Industria, innovación e infraestructura",
             "ODS 9: Industria, innovación e infraestructura",
             "ODS 5: Igualdad de género",
             "ODS 10: Reducción de las desigualdades",
             "ODS 12: Producción y consumo responsables"),
  value = c(2L,1L,3L,1L,2L,1L,
            3L,1L,1L,19L,1L,11L,13L,15L,
            8L,4L,4L,1L,1L,1L)
)


my_color <- 'd3.scaleOrdinal().domain(["Objetivo 1", "Objetivo 2","Objetivo 3", "Objetivo 4","ODS 3: Salud y bienestar", "ODS 5: Igualdad de género", "ODS 9: Industria, innovación e infraestructura", "ODS 10: Reducción de las desigualdades", "ODS 12: Producción y consumo responsables", "ODS 17: Alianzas para lograr los objetivos"]) 
.range(["#12A09A", "#1E5C4F" , "#941B80", "#F19100", "#4C9F38", "#FF3A21", "#FD6925", "#DD1367", "#BF8B2E", "purple", "#001B8C"])'

nodes <- data.frame(name=c(as.character(data_long$source), as.character(data_long$target)) %>% unique())


data_long$IDsource=match(data_long$source, nodes$name)-1 
data_long$IDtarget=match(data_long$target, nodes$name)-1

nodes$node_group <- gsub(" ", "_", nodes$name)


sankeyNetwork(Links = data_long, Nodes = nodes,
              Source = "IDsource", Target = "IDtarget",
              Value = "value", NodeID = "name", NodeGroup = "node_group",
              sinksRight=FALSE, colourScale=my_color, 
              nodeWidth=40, fontSize=13, nodePadding=20)
```

[image]